# Unicode in the standard TensorFlow format

Tags: python, unicode, tensorflow, protocol-buffers

Following the documentation [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/how_tos/reading_data/index.html#standard-tensorflow-format), I am trying to create features from unicode strings. Here is what the feature creation method looks like,

```
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))
```

This will raise an exception,

```
  File "/home/rklopfer/.virtualenvs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 512, in init
    copy.extend(field_value)
  File "/home/rklopfer/.virtualenvs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/containers.py", line 275, in extend
    new_values = [self._type_checker.CheckValue(elem) for elem in elem_seq_iter]
  File "/home/rklopfer/.virtualenvs/tf/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/type_checkers.py", line 108, in CheckValue
    raise TypeError(message)
TypeError: u'Gross' has type <type 'unicode'>, but expected one of: (<type 'str'>,)
```

Naturally if I wrap the `value` in a `str`, it fails on the first *actual* unicode character it encounters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

BytesList [definition](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/89e1cc59681b78e8193f899dca16474c19a7fc5b/tensorflow/core/example/feature.proto#L65) is in feature.proto and it is of type `repeated bytes`, this means that you need to pass it something that's convertible to a list of byte sequences.

There's more than one way to turn `unicode` into list of bytes, hence ambiguity. You could do it manually instead. IE, to use `UTF-8` encoding

```
value.encode("utf-8")
```

Answer (score 0):

Note Tensorflow now has built-in methods for dealing with unicode text, including conversions to and from many common formats.

https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/representation/unicode